# I need a vscode theme for presbyopia

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Does anyone know of a vscode theme designed specifically for people with presbyopia?

My eyes hurt a lot, especially when I tried to find the scroll bar.

I have tried with a lot of different themes, but I have not found anyone exclusively designed for people with presbytie

I will thank any help.

Note: I KNOW that the real solution is to get new glasses. I'm just looking to something to help while I'm waiting for them

Comment: Please mention the english translation of `presbytie`, what characteristics do you want, are the high contrast themes helpfull

Comment: what I found about `presbyopia` is not related to colors but contrast/focus, and with reading problems glasses might be a solution